# Get my Mac's computer name

Tags: macos, cocoa

How can I get the computer's name on a Mac? I'm talking about the same name as the one you can find in System Profiler under "Software".

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**Objective C**

The name I was looking for is:

```
[[NSHost currentHost] localizedName];
```

It returns "Jonathan's MacBook" rather than "Jonathans-Macbook", or "jonathans-macbook.local" which just `name` returns.

**Swift 3**

For Swift >= 3 use.

```
if let deviceName = Host.current().localizedName {
   print(deviceName)
}
```

Comment: Be aware that [NSHost currentHost] performs a blocking network lookup. On a slow network or a disconnected computer it will stop your application until the network call times out, unless you call it on a background thread.

Comment: Just pass an empty string when registering the service and your localised name will be automatically used, as recommended by apple

Comment: Is there a way to write this in Swift?

Comment: @dylan, yeah in swift 3: `Host.current().localizedName`

Comment: In swift it showing an error as ` Use of unresolved identifier 'Host' `

Comment: what about `NSProcessInfo.processInfo.hostName`?

Comment: FYI `NSHost` has been deprecated in macOS 12 Monterey.

Comment: The Swift code is not deprecated. It still works in macOS 13 Ventura.

Comment: That Apple Deprecated all compatible unix and non compatible Cocoa networking in macOS 12 doesn't mean anything. It will be working for much longer then your job contract.

Answer (score 14):

I use sysctlbyname("kern.hostname"), which does not block.
Please note that my helper method should only be used to retrieve string attributes, not integers.

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

- (NSString*) systemInfoString:(const char*)attributeName
{
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname(attributeName, NULL, &size, NULL, 0); // Get the size of the data.
    char* attributeValue = malloc(size);
    int err = sysctlbyname(attributeName, attributeValue, &size, NULL, 0);
    if (err != 0) {
        NSLog(@"sysctlbyname(%s) failed: %s", attributeName, strerror(errno));
        free(attributeValue);
        return nil;
    }
    NSString* vs = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:attributeValue];
    free(attributeValue);
    return vs;
}

- (NSString*) hostName
{
    NSArray* components = [[self systemInfoString:"kern.hostname"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    return components[0];
}
```

Comment: Best solution AFAIK, and not like `SCDynamicStoreCopyLocalHostName`, it will return necessary ".local" suffix.

Comment: nice solution as NSHost became deprecated.

Answer (score 12):

[NSHost](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHost_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what you want here:

```
NSHost *host;

host = [NSHost currentHost];
[host name];
```

Comment: Will that get be the user friendly name (so including things like spaces and apostrophes), or the dumber version where spaces are replaced with - and ' removed.

Comment: From the linked doc: `Can be either a simple hostname, such as @"sales", or a fully qualified domain name, such as @"sales.anycorp.com".`

Comment: No I mean will it be "Jonathan's MacBook" or "Jonathans-Macbook"?

Answer (score 7):

Using the **SystemConfiguration.framework**, which you must add to your project:

```
#include <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>

...

// Returns NULL/nil if no computer name set, or error occurred. OSX 10.1+
NSString *computerName = [(NSString *)SCDynamicStoreCopyComputerName(NULL, NULL) autorelease];

// Returns NULL/nil if no local hostname set, or error occurred. OSX 10.2+
NSString *localHostname = [(NSString *)SCDynamicStoreCopyLocalHostName(NULL) autorelease];
```

Comment: Please note Apple does not recommend using this method when registering a Bonjour service. More info in the [Technical Q&A QA1228](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1228/_index.html).

Comment: Just to clarify – the `ComputerName` and `LocalHostName` are distinct here. Apple recommend against using the LocalHostName since it is has stricter limitations than are necessary for Bonjour services – and the Bonjour automatic registration APIs use the ComputerName plus some deduplication magic for free.

Answer (score 3):

in terminal you have it with :

```
system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType | grep "Computer Name" | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d [:space:]
```

then in C you can get it with :

```
  FILE* stream = popen("system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType | grep \"Computer Name\" | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d [:space:]", "r");
  ostringstream hoststream;

  while(!feof(stream) && !ferror(stream))
  {
      char buf[128];
      int byteRead = fread( buf, 1, 128, stream);
      hoststream.write(buf, byteRead);
  }
```

Comment: I was getting error for `[:space:]` so I changed last part as `tr -d ' '` and then it worked ok for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one that doesn't block:

```
NSString* name = [(NSString*)CSCopyMachineName() autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5+

Since `Host` will be deprecated in a future version of macOS, try:

```
let computerName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.hostName
```